# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, syntax-error, var

Its my first time learning to program Javascript and been working on this program to take 99 drinks on the wall till it reachs zero.. I been working on this program since 12am learning JS... its now 3am and im going bonkers and unable to see my mistake.

Where did i go wrong?
How can i prevent this in the future?

Its my first crack at making a JS program so please dont rip into me too bad i litterly just opened a book and started at 11:30pm till now asking at 3am..

Thanks guys or girls!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My First JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var drinks = "Energy Drink";
var lyrics = "";
var cans = 99;
    while (cans > 0) {

      lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drinks + " on the 
      wall <br>";
      lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drinks + "<br>";
      lyrics = lyrics + " Take on down pass it around, <br>";
      
      if (cans > 1)
        {
        lyrics = lyrics + (cans-1) + " cans of " + drink + " on 
        the wall <br>"
        }

     ** else *This is where my error seems to come from????*
        {
        lyrics = lyrics + "No more cans of " + drink + " on the 
        wall <br>";
        }
      cans = cans - 1;
    }
    document.write(lyrics);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var drinks = "Energy Drink";
  var lyrics = "";
  var cans = 99;
  while (cans > 0) {

    lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drinks + " on the wall <br>";
    lyrics = lyrics + cans + " cans of " + drinks + "<br>";
    lyrics = lyrics + " Take on down pass it around, <br>";
    
    if (cans > 1) {
      lyrics = lyrics + (cans-1) + " cans of " + drinks + " on the wall <br>";
    } else {
      lyrics = lyrics + "No more cans of " + drinks + " on the wall <br>";
    }
    cans = cans - 1;
  }
  document.write(lyrics);
```

You did newlines in vars.

You writed `drink` instead of `drinks`

Change `<script>` by `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Thank you! it turns out my code did not work because i did not add the *s* to "drink" in the IF/ ELSE statements

Answer (score 0):

Thank you pirs! It turns out my code did not work because i did not add the *s* to "drink" in the IF/ ELSE statements. I had a the variable spelled wrong which caused the code not to print.